# Why does Selenium think this HTML span is empty?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to scrape NASDAQ's website for real time stock quotes. When I use chrome developer tools, I can see the span I want to target is (for example with Alphabet as of writing this) `<span class="symbol-page-header__pricing-price">$2952.77</span>.` I want to extract the $2952.77. My python code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)


def get_last_price(ticker):
    driver.get(f"https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/{ticker}")
    price = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "symbol-page-header__pricing-last-price")
    print(price.get_attribute('text'))
    
    # p = price.get_attribute('innerHTML')


get_last_price('googl')
```

The above code returns 'None'. If you uncomment out the line defining p and print it's output, it shows that Selenium thinks the span is empty.

```
            <span class="symbol-page-header__pricing-price"></span>
```

I don't understand why this is happening. My thought is that it has something to do with the fact that it's probably being rendered dynamically with Javascript, but I thought that was an advantage of Selenium say as opposed to BeautifulSoup... there shouldn't be an issue right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) of NASDAQ's [Coinbase Global](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/coin) your [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) selects 2 nodes and the the one you don't want is:

[image: coinbase]

---

### Solution

To print the price information you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *XPATH* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/coin")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='symbol-page-header__pricing-price' and text()]"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/coin")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='symbol-page-header__pricing-price' and text()]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  $263.91
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 nodes with the class `symbol-page-header__pricing-price`. The node that you want is under

```
<div class="symbol-page-header__pricing-details symbol-page-header__pricing-details--current symbol-page-header__pricing-details--decrease"></div>
```

So, you need to get inside this `div` first to ensure you scrape the right one.

Anyways, I'd recommend you to use `BeautifulSoup` to scrape the HTML text after you’ve finished interacting with the dynamic website with `selenium`. This will save your time and your memory. It has no need to keep running the browser, so, it would be better if you terminate it (i.e. `driver.close()`) and use `BeautifulSoup` to explore the static HTML text.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

def get_last_price(ticker):
    driver.get(f"https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/{ticker}")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
    header = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'symbol-page-header__pricing-details symbol-page-header__pricing-details--current symbol-page-header__pricing-details--decrease'})
    price = header.find('span', attrs={'class':'symbol-page-header__pricing-price'})
    print(price)
    print(price.text)

get_last_price('googl')
```

Output:

```
>>> <span class="symbol-page-header__pricing-price">$2952.77</span>
>>> $2952.77
```